# Title Issue Prestashop Website

Tags: file, path, web, prestashop, title

Can you tell me where is the title's location (script path) on my Prestashop folder, because I want to remove one "Wisalova" on it.

[image: title issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything related to metas is generated by `Meta` class, located in /classes/Meta.php. You're looking for `getHomeMetas` method.
The

```
$ret['meta_title'] = ...
```

Is the line that returns contents displayed in your `title` tag. However, do not modify the method here. Create a file: `/override/classes/Meta.php`. The file contents:

```
class Meta extends MetaCore
{
    public static function getHomeMetas($id_lang, $page_name)
    {
        $metas = parent::getHomeMetas($id_lang, $page_name);

        $metas['meta_title'] = 'My altered title'; // this is where you modify your title

        return $metas;
    }
}
```

Again, do not modify the original file located in classes/Meta.php - the changes in the original files will disappear when you update your store to a newer prestashop version.